# How to make current date independent from System Date in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Jquery

html

```
<input type="text" id="travel_date"/>
```

js

```
<script>
       $("#travel_date").datepicker({
          dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
          changeYear: true,
          changeMonth: true,
          numberOfMonths:[1,2],
          maxDate: $("#return_on").datepicker("getDate"),
          minDate: new Date(),
          onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#return_on" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
            $( "#return_date" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
          }
        }).attr('readonly','readonly');
</script>
```

Issue : If i am changing the system date then datepicker dates also changing.

Example:

```
     Today's date is : 19/09/2014.
     System date (I changed) : 10/09/2014
```

and in input box default i have given `new Date();` Today's date so it is coming 10/09/2014 how can i prevent this issue.

Required output: Real current date should come. if i will change the system date to old also.

Any suggestion/help...

Comment: what date you want to set, is there any default date you have?

Comment: No i want whatever is current date, that should come.

Comment: but then system date will be current date and if you change it then you have to read current date from any API which is available on internet.

Comment: can you tell me any API name for getting the current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render a hidden field with today's date from your own web server.

```
<input type="hidden" id="datetoday" value="Set Value according to your server code in dd-mm-yy format as expected by datepicker dateformat options you set"/>
```

and then change minDate to a value from hidden field.

```
minDate: $("#datetoday").val(),
```